# Finding the range of this function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$F(x) = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x^2 }{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)$$
My attempt:
[image]

I don't understand where I went wrong

Comment: Can you evaluate your expression?  What is your interval?  Is the smaller number on the left?

Comment: Can you express the range in terms or actual values-- not in terms of f.  what *is* f(0) and f(whosit)?

Comment: @fleablood I don't know what f(whatever) is, but it certainly won't give me the correct answer. I would need that expression to equal 0 to give me the correct answer for the range which is $(0,\pi/2]$

Comment: If you plot value of x i.e $\pm\sqrt \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ on number line then you'll find $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt1+x^2}$ is increase function when x is $\ge $$\sqrt \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$ or $\le$  $$-\sqrt \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$$  While you assumed it to be 0.

Comment: The evaluation of the domain is probably wrong, but at the end I think you forced the right value. The minimum is not at 0, anyway.

Comment: The interval $[\pm f(\sqrt{\frac 1+\sqrt{5}/}, f(0)]$ doesn't make any sense for many reasons.  To begin with you aren't finish.  $f(k)$ is not a proper value.  Second of all a interval must have distinct endpoints $[\pm 3, 2]$ is utterly meaningless and $\pm 3$ is not a distinct value.  And you made no effort to show that $\pm f(k) < f(0)$.  If the *minima* is at x = 0 then wouldn't the range be [k = f(0), something] and not [something, k]?

Comment: @iti shree, n74 https://www.desmos.com/calculator try plotting it the minima is at x = 0. You can confirm this by differentiation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument of the $\arccos$, which is $\frac {x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ must be restricted to $[-1,1]$ and is always positive.  It will cover $[0,1]$ as $x$ ranges from $0$ to $\sqrt{\frac 12(1+\sqrt 5)}$.  The values of $x$ are unimportant.  The range is from $0$ to $\frac \pi 2$ from the definition of $\arccos$

Comment: I guess I'm troubled by the fact that solving for $\frac {x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ = 1 gives me x = +/- $\sqrt{\frac 12(1+\sqrt 5)}$ and substituting this back into the expression doesn't give me 1

Comment: [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2F(sqrt(1%2Bx%5E2))+with+x%3Dsqrt((1%2Bsqrt(5))%2F2)) does get $1$.  Check your calculation.